# Error scaling a video using libav filters

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I need to batch-process a bunch of videos to scale their height to 240 keeping the aspect ratio same. The command that gets the job *almost* done is:

```
$ avconv -threads 4 -ss 0.0 -i input.avi \
-map 0:0,0:0 -map 0:1,0:1 -vf "scale=-1:240" -y -f mpegts \
-async -1 -vcodec libx264 -vcodec libx264 -flags2 +fast \
-flags +loop -g 30 -bufsize 1024k \
-b 200k -bt 220k -qmax 48 -qmin 2 -r 20 -acodec libmp3lame \
-ab 44k -ar 44100 -ac 2 output.ts
```

The interesting part, as you can see, is `-vf "scale=-1:240"`

This works on videos where the scaled output width turns out to be an even number. Otherwise, I get the following error message:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fc4f8821e00] width not divisible by 2 (341x240)
```

How do I overcome this?

Edit:
As per this [link](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/309), I tried using `-vf "scale=trunc(oh/a/2)*2:240"` which outputs a movie but the resulting video quality is really poor.

Edit #2:
This is **not a duplicate** as it's wrongly marked. This question was posted much earlier than the other one.

Comment: As for the duplicate it doesn't really matter which question is older. Typically, the question with fewer votes gets marked as the duplicate.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard That makes sense too, but contradicts SO's own definition in the box above, particularly - "marked as duplicate... This question has been asked before and already has an answer".

Comment: The intention was to understand SO's guidelines, not argue who is first. But if it sounded so, I'll stop here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update; you can now use:

```
-vf scale=-2:240
```

[Is there a good list of mp4 supported resolutions and a way to have ffmpeg calculate the width after modifying by set height ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40600762/#40601020)

---

The link actually says:

```sh
scale="854:trunc(ow/a/2)*2"
```

which correctly scales the height to an even number, if you wish to scale the
width you must use this idiom:

```sh
-vf scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:240"
#                  ^
#                 /
#       notice ---
```

Math behind it:

```sh
iw   ow
-- = --
ih   oh

ow = (iw * oh) / ih
ow = oh * a
```

Comment: What do those abbreviations stand for?

Comment: @StevenPenny That's absolutely right. Of course the aspect ratio needs to be multiplied and not divided. Thanks