# How to have ffmpeg calculate the width after modifying by set height ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, resolution, aspect-ratio

After finding the resolution was the source of all my webm to MP4 codec conversion errors on my Android. I came across another problem. To break down my question:

What all MP4 resolutions are supported on most devices? I know they go by p from certain height value for them to work. 720p /?X720 for example.

Is there an easier way to calculate the width based from the height change while keeping the ratio?

```
ffmpeg -i old.webm -t 00:00:03 -s 320x240 new.mp4
```

I currently use the -s setting perimeter from my testing example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard ratio for widescreens is 16:9 and the typical list of resolutions used is

```
256x144, 426x240, 640x360, 854x480, 960x540, 1024x576, 1280x720, 1920x1080, 2560x1440, 3840x2160
```

If you directly use the scale filter, you can tell ffmpeg to maintain the aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i old.webm -t 00:00:03 -vf scale=-2:240 new.mp4
```

In the command above, `scale=-2:240` tells ffmpeg to scale to height 240, select a width so that aspect ratio is maintained, and then adjust that value so that the width and height is a multiple of 2 (required for H.264/MP4). If you did not care whether the value was even, you could just use `-1`.