# Different video players showing incorrect mp4 resolution after ffmpeg conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, resolution

After getting help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40601020/6318164 on how to convert webm to mp4. The result avoiding losing the video ratio by setting the height resolution with `-vf scale=-2:720`.

I then came across another problem. I've found both width and height had to be supported for the video players, when I thought it was just the height that had to be specified.

After browsing around I found this script https://stackoverflow.com/a/35487394/6318164 were I can change the video's canvas to a common width and height standard. It shrinks the video to fit inside the center of specified canvas without losing the ratio while filling the empty space with black padding if I'm correct, which is the result I want.

However, although it solved the playback problems in all the players, I've found different video players show different resolution information of the same video.

I've modified the script here for Linux terminal use.

```
X=1280; Y=720; ffmpeg -i old.webm -t 5 -vf "scale=min(iw*$Y/ih\,$X):min($Y\,ih*$X/iw),pad=$X:$Y:($X-iw)/2:($Y-ih)/2" new.mp4
```

This is the research on the resolution differences I've found for value I set.

```
X=1280; Y=720;

webm          -> mp4
=========================================================
1280x752      -> 1280x720 X-plore (Android)
Not supported -> 1339x720 Telegram (Android)
1338x752      -> 1340x720 GNOME MPlayer (Linux)
Not supported -> ???????? Built-in Video Player (Android)
```

The question is, I'm I doing anything wrong with the ffmpeg conversion to return incorrect resolutions for different players? I checked out some other videos I have and they show the correct resolutions except this converted one.

**Edit**

With the help of the accepted answer. This was my working output if anyone needs it:

```
X=1280; Y=720; ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf "scale='if(gt(a*sar,16/9),${X},${Y}*iw*sar/ih)':'if(gt(a*sar,16/9),${X}*ih/iw/sar,${Y})',pad=${X}:${Y}:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `setsar=1` after pad.

Also, your scale expression doesn't account for videos with non-square pixels. Use the expression in this [answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/19853/1871).